# I want to find all report.txt and paste them into another folder with rename

Tags: linux

I have large number of report.txt files in different different folder in a disk. Some file are named as Report.txt and some with suffix like reportmonday.txt.
So i want to find and copy all the files contain report to a single folder with rename if already exists. Like
report.txt
report1.txt
report2.txt

I tried some command

**find . -type f -iname 'report*' -exec mv {} {}_renamed /home/ram/allreport**

this command does not renaming my filename but overrighting. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat convoluted way to solve this:

- execute the following: `find . -type f -iname \*report\* | awk 'BEGIN{com="ls /home/ram/allreport/*[Rr]eport*|awk -F. \047{print $NF}\047|sort -n|tail -n1"; com | getline result}{result++; printf "mv \"%s\" /home/ram/allreport/report.%s\n",$0,result}'`
- **if the output of the above looks sensible** add a  `| bash` to the end of the above command and run it again ... `find . -type f -iname \*report\* | awk 'BEGIN{com="ls /home/ram/allreport/*[Rr]eport*|awk -F. \047{print $NF}\047|sort -n|tail -n1"; com | getline result}{result++; printf "mv \"%s\" /home/ram/allreport/report.%s\n",$0,result}'|bash`

Here a pretty version of the awk part w/ explanatory words:

```
BEGIN { # prerequisite action, this happens before we check what we "find"
        com = "ls /home/ram/allreport/*[Rr]eport*|awk -F. '{print $NF}'|sort -n|tail -n1"  # we execute an ls on the target directory to get the highest existing report number
        com | getline result                                            # and store the number in the variable result
}

{  # here the processing of find's output starts
        result++                                                        # increase result by one for each line 
        printf "mv \"%s\" /home/ram/allreport/report.%s\n", $0, result  # print the command we want to execute, 
                                                                        # a mv of the original file to the target directory with a new name and the counter "result" tacked on.
}
```

Comment: NO Luck no such file or directory. I couldn't figure out where to put | bash

 
find . -type f -iname \*report\* | awk 'BEGIN{com="ls /home/ram/allreport/*[Rr]eport*|awk -F. \047{print $NF}\047|sort -n|tail -n1"; com | getline result}{result++; printf "mv \"%s\" /home/ram/allreport/report.%s\n",$0,result}'
ls: cannot access '/home/ram/allreport/*[Rr]eport*': No such file or directory
mv "./untitled folder/untitled folder/untitled folder/report.txt" /home/ram/allreport/report.1

Comment: Oh, ok, that's a corner-case I hadn't contemplated.  Just create an empty file `/home/ram/allreport/report.txt` (assuming you already created the directory `allreport`).

Comment: no error is showing but still not moving to to allreport folder. Thanks find . -type f -iname \*report\* | awk 'BEGIN{com="ls /home/ram/allreport/*[Rr]eport*|awk -F. \047{print $NF}\047|sort -n|tail -n1"; com | getline result}{result++; printf "mv \"%s\" /home/ram/allreport/report.%s\n",$0,result}'
mv "./untitled folder/untitled folder/untitled folder/report.txt" /home/ram/allreport/report.1

Comment: Yes, as I said ... if the output looks sensible, pipe it to bash ... I'll edit the answer for you @alok so you see what I mean

Comment: Thanks So Much Man You saved my life. People like you keep new learners motivated. Thanks buddy

Comment: You're welcome @alok ... feel free to accept my answer if it now does what you need. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script that will check any file contains the word 'report' (case insensitive) in it's name and will copy to a desired directory. If a file already exists in that name under the directory it will try to rename `report1.txt`, `report2.txt` etc. if it can't rename to that number it will assign a random suffix. Like `report1354.txt`.
Mind that it will check if directory exists to. If directory does not exist the script will create one.

```
#!/bin/bash

# make sure the below variable does not contain tailing '/'
# it should be '/home/tfp/allreports' not '/home/tfp/allreports/'
ALL_REPORTS_DIRECTORY="/home/tfp/allreports"
FILE_NAMES_ARRAY=$(find . -type f -name "*[rR][eE][pP][oO][rR][tT]*" 2>>/dev/null)
RENAME_SUFFIX=1

if [[ -d ${ALL_REPORTS_DIRECTORY} ]]; then
    echo "directory exists. not creating"
else
    mkdir ${ALL_REPORTS_DIRECTORY}
    echo "directory doesn't exists. creating"
fi

# to do give random suffix to files under subfolder
for file in ${FILE_NAMES_ARRAY}; do
    file_name=$(basename $file)
    if [[ -f "${ALL_REPORTS_DIRECTORY}/${file_name}" ]]; then
        if [[ -f "${ALL_REPORTS_DIRECTORY}/report${RENAME_SUFFIX}.txt" ]]; then
            random_suffix=$RANDOM
            echo "  couldn't rename '${file_name}'. suffix '${RENAME_SUFFIX}' already exists so giving random suffix"
            cp $file ${ALL_REPORTS_DIRECTORY}/report${random_suffix}.txt
            echo "  '$file' -> new name: report${random_suffix}.txt"
        else
            echo "file '${file}' exists under '${ALL_REPORTS_DIRECTORY}'. renaming to report${RENAME_SUFFIX}.txt"
            cp $file ${ALL_REPORTS_DIRECTORY}/report${RENAME_SUFFIX}.txt
            echo "  '$file' -> new name: report${RENAME_SUFFIX}.txt"
        fi
        RENAME_SUFFIX=$(echo $((${RENAME_SUFFIX}+1)))
    else
        cp $file ${ALL_REPORTS_DIRECTORY}
        echo "copied '${file}'"
    fi
done
```

Here's some example output.

```
$ls

myreport.txt  report1.txt  report3.txt  report55.txt  report6.txt  Report.txt  script.sh  sundayReport.txt  testfolder
```

```
$bash script.sh

directory exists. not creating
copied './Report.txt'
copied './testfolder/rePorT.txt'
copied './testfolder/RReport.txt'
copied './myreport.txt'
copied './sundayReport.txt'
copied './report1.txt'
copied './report6.txt'
copied './report55.txt'
copied './report3.txt'
```

```
$bash script.sh

directory exists. not creating
  couldn't rename 'Report.txt'. suffix '1' already exists so giving random suffix
  './Report.txt' -> new name: report3262.txt
file './testfolder/rePorT.txt' exists under '/home/tfp/allreports'. renaming to report2.txt
  './testfolder/rePorT.txt' -> new name: report2.txt
  couldn't rename 'RReport.txt'. suffix '3' already exists so giving random suffix
  './testfolder/RReport.txt' -> new name: report6693.txt
file './myreport.txt' exists under '/home/tfp/allreports'. renaming to report4.txt
  './myreport.txt' -> new name: report4.txt
file './sundayReport.txt' exists under '/home/tfp/allreports'. renaming to report5.txt
  './sundayReport.txt' -> new name: report5.txt
  couldn't rename 'report1.txt'. suffix '6' already exists so giving random suffix
  './report1.txt' -> new name: report31626.txt
file './report6.txt' exists under '/home/tfp/allreports'. renaming to report7.txt
  './report6.txt' -> new name: report7.txt
file './report55.txt' exists under '/home/tfp/allreports'. renaming to report8.txt
  './report55.txt' -> new name: report8.txt
file './report3.txt' exists under '/home/tfp/allreports'. renaming to report9.txt
  './report3.txt' -> new name: report9.txt
```

```
$bash script.sh

directory exists. not creating
  couldn't rename 'Report.txt'. suffix '1' already exists so giving random suffix
  './Report.txt' -> new name: report32658.txt
  couldn't rename 'rePorT.txt'. suffix '2' already exists so giving random suffix
  './testfolder/rePorT.txt' -> new name: report1976.txt
  couldn't rename 'RReport.txt'. suffix '3' already exists so giving random suffix
  './testfolder/RReport.txt' -> new name: report26897.txt
  couldn't rename 'myreport.txt'. suffix '4' already exists so giving random suffix
  './myreport.txt' -> new name: report31297.txt
  couldn't rename 'sundayReport.txt'. suffix '5' already exists so giving random suffix
  './sundayReport.txt' -> new name: report29608.txt
  couldn't rename 'report1.txt'. suffix '6' already exists so giving random suffix
  './report1.txt' -> new name: report7259.txt
  couldn't rename 'report6.txt'. suffix '7' already exists so giving random suffix
  './report6.txt' -> new name: report16691.txt
  couldn't rename 'report55.txt'. suffix '8' already exists so giving random suffix
  './report55.txt' -> new name: report12176.txt
  couldn't rename 'report3.txt'. suffix '9' already exists so giving random suffix
  './report3.txt' -> new name: report11087.txt
```

final `ls` from destination directory

```
$ls -lah

total 8,0K
drwxrwxr-x  2 tfp tfp 4,0K Sep 15 18:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 46 tfp tfp 4,0K Sep 15 18:32 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 myreport.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:37 report11087.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:37 report12176.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:37 report16691.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:37 report1976.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report1.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:37 report26897.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:37 report29608.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report2.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:37 report31297.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report31626.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report3262.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:37 report32658.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report3.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report4.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report55.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report5.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report6693.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report6.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:37 report7259.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report7.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report8.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 report9.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 rePorT.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 Report.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 RReport.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 tfp tfp    0 Sep 15 18:36 sundayReport.txt
```